# Sum of fraction of factorials

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, factorial

Can anybody explain this?

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\frac{m-1}2}\frac{(2k)!(2m-2k)!}{(2k-1)(2m-2k-1)k!^2(m-k)!^2}=\frac{(2m)!}{(2 m-1)m!^2}$$

I did actually simplify this to:

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\frac{m-1}2}\frac{1}{(2k-1)(2m-2k-1)}{2k\choose k}{2m-2k\choose m-k}=\frac{1}{2m-1}{2m\choose m}$$

Does anybody have an idea on how to show this equality holds?

I tried proof by induction, but I think that is an hopeless idea.

Comment: Do you know that $m$ is odd? Or does the sum end with $\lfloor \frac {m-1}2\rfloor$?

Comment: No there is no need for $m$ to be odd, the sum ends as $\lfloor \frac{m-1}2\rfloor$ indeed. Maple simplifies {simplify(sum((2*k)!*(2*m-2*k)!/((2*k-1)*(2*m-2*k-1)*k!^2*(m-k)!^2),k=1..(m-1)/2)-(2*m)!/((2*m-1)*m!^2))} to $0$, which actually means it works for even $m$ as well.

Comment: I evaluated some both sides for some small values of $m$, and it turns out that it is only true when $m$ is odd. Maybe Mathematica and Maple handle the rounding different.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry for my blind trust in Maple, you are right: $m$ must be odd.

Comment: For even $m$, it is true is you sum up to $\lfloor \frac {m-1}2\rfloor$ and also take half of the $\lfloor\frac{m-1}2\rfloor+1$ term.

Comment: $$\sum_{k=0}^m{2k\choose k}{2m-2k\choose m-k}=4^m$$

Comment: It can also be rewritten to
$$
\frac 1m\binom{2m-2}{m-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\frac{\binom{2k-2}{k-1}}k\frac{\binom{2(m-k)-2}{(m-k)-1}}{m-k}
$$
The terms on the RHS are multiples of $\frac 12$, but multiplying by $2$ will yield a sum of integers.

Comment: [Vandermonde's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde's_identity) is $$\sum_{k=0}^m\displaystyle\frac{\ \ {m\choose k}^2}{2m\choose m}=1$$ This sum can be rewritten as $$\sum_{k=0}^{\left[\frac{m-1}2\right]}\frac{\ \ {m\choose k}^2}{2m\choose 2k}\cdot\frac{2m-1}{(2k-1)(2m-2k-1)}=1$$

Comment: That's it! I just don't yet understand the magic in deriving that second equation from the first one, changing the limit of the sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equality is clearly false for $m=1$, so let's try to prove it for $m\geq 2$ only.

Let $C_n= \frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$ denote the $n$-th Catalan number. The sum can then be rewritten in quite compact form (similar to **Lucian**'s suggestion):

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{k=1}^{(m-1)/2} \frac{2}{k}\binom{2k-2}{k-1} \frac{2}{m-k}\binom{2(m-k-1)}{m-k-1} & = & \frac{2}{m}\binom{2(m-1)}{m-1} \\
2\sum_{k=1}^{(m-1)/2} C_{k-1}C_{m-k-1} & = & C_{m-1}
\end{eqnarray}$$

After shifting and setting $M=m-2$, we get 
$$2\sum_{k=0}^{(M-1)/2} C_{k}C_{M-k} = C_{M+1}$$

Thanks to symmetry, we have:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor(M-1)/2\rfloor} C_{k}C_{M-k} = \sum_{k=\lfloor M/2\rfloor+1}^{M} C_{k}C_{M-k}$$

For odd $M$ (which is equivalent to odd $m$), this implies
$$2\sum_{k=0}^{(M-1)/2} C_{k}C_{M-k} = \sum_{k=0}^M C_{k}C_{M-k}$$

But the last sum is well-known sum for $C_{M+1}$; exactly what we were trying to prove! Q.E.D.
(Combinatorial insight is that $C_{M+1}$ counts the number of binary trees with $(M+1)$ nodes and each such tree contains left and right sub-tree which have $M$ nodes in total.)

As **Ragnar** observed, for even $m$, we'd need to add twice the missing central term $C_{m/2-1}^2$ to the original sum to make it equal to the right-hand side.

Comment: Wow thank you very, very much!